# 2 different model login forms in single view, Rails 4 and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have created modal login forms for **Advertisement** and **User**. They are completely diferent from each other.

My goal is create ability to login as a user or advertisement in  same view. So visitor selects to login as user -> user login form shows up and so on.

In some sources I read that I need to add some lines to Application_helper for ability to login as user from any place.

**Application_helper.rb**

```
def resource_name
    :user

    #tried thing below
    :user, :advertisement # got syntax error from this line.

  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]

  end
```

I tried different variations of this code.

But no result.

My login forms looks like this :

```
<%= form_for(resource,:html => {id:"form-signin"}, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

    ....

<%end%>
```

I tried to use like:

```
<%= form_for(@advertisement,:html => {id:"form-signin"}, as: @advertisement, url: session_path(@advertisement)) do |f| %>
```

and

```
  <%= form_for(@user,:html => {id:"form-signin"}, as: @user, url: session_path(@user)) do |f| %>
```

I got this error :`Could not find a valid mapping for nil`

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :lockable
       #  confirmable

         belongs_to :country
         belongs_to :gender
         has_many :reviews, :dependent => :destroy


                 acts_as_voter
                  acts_as_votable
           validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: true
end
```

**Advertisement.rb**

```
class Advertisement < ActiveRecord::Base
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :authentication_keys => [:name]
 include Humanizer
  require_human_on :create

 .......


end
```

Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: How does your user and advertisement model look?

Comment: @kurenn Updated my question with some code.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your server?, why are you overriding methods on the `ApplicationHelper` ?

Comment: @kurenn Yes, I tried to restart. No change. Because that is only way to able login from any controller action. I have login partials inside application layout.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/IcaliaLabs/acts_as_user it might help you set up this multiple role issue